# Программа выполняется непоследовательно (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
В программе есть поля для ввода номера телефона и пароля.
Программа должна подключаться к базе данных Firebase и проверить, есть ли пользователь с таким номером телефона в базе данных и если есть - выполнять код дальше, а если нет - выдавать соответствующий текст.
Но программа идёт дальше независимо от того, есть ли нужные данные в БД, а потом выдаёт текст о том, что этих данных нет.
Код программы:

```
button_login.setOnClickListener {
        var check = true

        check = userCheck()

        if (check) {
            if (!phoneCheck(ed_phone_of_user.text)) {
                warning_message_phone.text = "Пожалуйста, введите правильный номер телефона"
                warning_message_phone.isVisible = true
                check = false
            }
            if (ed_password.text.length < 6) {
                warning_message_password.text = "Пароль должен содержать минимум 6 символов"
                warning_message_password.isVisible = true
                check = false
            }

            if (check) {
                // Здесь далее выполняется программа
            }
        }
    }

private fun userCheck(): Boolean {
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    var check = true
    val source = Source.SERVER
    val phone = convertPhone(ed_phone_of_user.text).trim()
        val userRef = db.collection("Users").document(phone)
        userRef.get(source)
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                if (documents == null) {
                    warning_message_phone.text = "Такой номер телефона не зарегистрирован"
                    warning_message_phone.isVisible = true
                    check = false

                } else if (documents["Password"]?.equals(ed_password.text.toString()) == false) {
                    warning_message_password.text = "Неверный пароль"
                    warning_message_password.isVisible = true
                    check = false
                }
            }
        return check
}
```

То есть он сначала выдаёт сообщение о том, что номер телефона введён неверно, а потом этот текст заменяется текстом о том, что такого номера телефона в базе нет (хотя по задумке, если телефона в БД нет, то дальнейшей проверки быть не должно и выполнение программы прерывается)

Comment: код addOnSuccessListener выполняется асинхронно, возврат из функции происходит сразу, а код в переданном listener выполняется через определённое время (когда загрузятся данные)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Firebase работает в асинхронном режиме используя коллбэк, то есть в момент когда вызывается по референсу .get() создается параллельный поток в котором приложение запрашивает у Firebase данные, при этом приложение не ждет эти данные и идет дальше выполнять код. Когда данные с сервера наконец приходят - автоматически вызывается блок внутри `.addOnSuccessListener{}`. По этому в момент вызова `if (check)` данные еще не пришли с сервера и не изменили переменную check, а метод `userCheck` возвращает первоначальное значение check (true).

Правильным решением будет вынесение проверки номера телефона в отдельный метод, который будет вызываться изнутри `.addOnSuccessListener{}`, то есть когда данные по факту пришли.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, всё заработало!

Answer (score 2):

Проблему понял и исправил 
Если кто-то столкнулся с такой же проблемой, то объясню как её решил я: 
Весь исполняемый код нужно добавить в блок .addOnSuccessListener{}
Вот как у меня вышло:

```
button_login.setOnClickListener {
        if (!phoneCheck(ed_phone_of_user.text)) {
            warning_message_phone.text = "Пожалуйста, введите правильный номер телефона"
            warning_message_phone.isVisible = true
        }
        else if (ed_password.text.length < 6) {
            warning_message_password.text = "Пароль должен содержать минимум 6 символов"
            warning_message_password.isVisible = true
        }
        else {
            val db = Firebase.firestore
            val source = Source.SERVER
            val userRef = db.collection("Users").document(convertPhone(ed_phone_of_user.text))
            userRef.get(source)
                .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                    if (!documents.exists()) {
                        warning_message_phone.text = "Такой номер телефона не зарегистрирован"
                        warning_message_phone.isVisible = true
                    } else if (!documents?.get("Password")
                            ?.equals(ed_password.text.toString())!!
                    ) {
                        warning_message_password.text = "Неверный пароль"
                        warning_message_password.isVisible = true
                    }  else {
                        // Тут исполняемый код
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```